# formatted print of structures contents and fieldnames in matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, struct, printf, octave, cell-array

I need to print to command window the contents of a structure with corresponding field names and some text around every structure element.

i.e.  `This something [fieldname(i)] has the value of [struct.fieldname(i) value] something.`

After half a day of headache I ended up with an expression (which does not work) and a loop (which works).

Question - is there a way to do this without a loop?

Code:

```
box.apples = 25
box.cherries = 0.5
box.iron = 0.085

% Loop method (works)
for i = (1:length(struct2cell(box))) ;
    printf('There are %.3f kg of %s in the box \n', struct2cell(box){i}, fieldnames(box){i})
end
% Single expression method (doesn't work)
printf('There are %.3f kg of %s in the box \n', struct2cell(box){:}, fieldnames(box){:})
```

The loop returns a sensible output exactly as I want:

```
There are 25.000 kg of apples in the box 
There are 0.500 kg of cherries in the box
There are 0.085 kg of iron in the box
```

Just the `printf` expression however returns this weird output:

```
There are 25.000 kg of  in the box
There are 0.085 kg of apples in the box
There are 99.000 kg of herries in the box
There are 105.000 kg of ron in the box
```

Advice appreciated

Comment: Did you make sure your box was cleared before you started? There wasn't anywhere in the code you posted where 99 and 105 would be inputted.

Comment: The code you provided gives an error, even for the loop version? What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @Flynn I can verify that the 105 magically appears, I get some other unexpected values too. I expect the 105 comes from the missing `i` from `iron`, as `char(105) = 'i'`, similarly `char(99) = 'c'` from `'cherries'`.

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for the hint on char conversion, I did not spot it! I am on Octave 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding my 2¢ to the above answers.

"Without a loop" is not necessarily *always* faster. Especially now with matlab's JIT-compiler for loops. So don't just avoid loops and end up with ugly-looking code-golf just for the sake of having a one-liner. Not to mention, one-liners *do not necessarily equal vectorisation*. If in doubt about speed, do a simple test-case benchmark.

Furthermore loops are generally much more readable, so unless you get a massive speedup from avoiding it, it's generally not necessarily worth sacrificing readability for the sake of micro-optimisations.

Having said that, here's how I would have written that loop:

```
  for CellStr = fieldnames(box).'
    Name = CellStr{1};
    fprintf('There are %.3f kg of %s in the box\n', box.(Name), Name)
  end
```

Or, if you're using octave, octave specifically provides the following lovely syntax:

```
for [Val, Field] = box
  fprintf('There are %.3f kg of %s in the box\n', Val, Field)
end
```

Some benchmarks on my machine (octave, no JIT compilation, time elapsed after 10000 iterations):

```
one-liner in answers above = 0.61343 seconds
top loop shown above       = 0.92640 seconds
bottom loop shown above    = 0.41643 seconds <-- wins
loop shown in the question = 1.6744  seconds
```

So, see, in this particular case, one of the for-loop approaches is in fact *faster* than the one-liner approach.

---

<sub>Also note that `box` is the name of a function in matlab / octave; it's generally a bad idea to use variable names that shadow builtin functions. You can generally get around that by using Capital letters for variables, or simply look for a function by that name before calling your variable that</sub>

Comment: absolutely true and the `for [Val, Field] = box` syntax is really lovely +1

Answer (score 4):

In GNU Octave (see Wolfies anwer for Matlab):

```
box.apples = 25
box.cherries = 0.5
box.iron = 0.085
printf('There are %.3f kg of %s in the box \n',
       horzcat(struct2cell(box),fieldnames(box))'{:});
```

and the "105.000" appears because you are feeding 'iron' as %f. Check this out (which should explain your strange result):

```
printf ('%f', 'iron')
```

Comment: `(struct2cell(box),fieldnames(box))'{:}` will definitely not work in matlab, but the OP seems to be using octave anyway and it's a neat solution for it.

Comment: `printf` also doesn't work in MATLAB, see my answer for summary.

Comment: @Andy
Thanks a lot, I should have asked earlier!
I´m not sure why iron gets fed to the %f, especially why only the first char.. I will need to think your answer through.

Oh forgot to metnion I´m on Octave 4.2.1

Answer (score 2):

This method should work for both MATLAB and Octave:

```
c = vertcat(struct2cell(box).',fieldnames(box).');
fprintf('There are %.3f kg of %s in the box \n', c{:});
```

---

In MATLAB you must *end* a statement with parentheses `()` where they are used. So you cannot do

```
c = struct2cell(box){:};
```

and must instead do

```
c = struct2cell(box);
c = c{:};
```

MATLAB also requires that you use `fprintf`, not `printf`. You can see some language differences [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB).

---